# Classic bluetooth package for iOS and android possible?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth

After [learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64417509/basic-flutter-bluetooth-questions) properly about BLE and bluetooth in general, I decided to do my project with classic bluetooth as BLE does not adjust no my needs.

I found no packages for classic bluetooth that support both android and iOS. What I found is issue [#23562](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23562) stating that "*it seems, that it is not possible to desing application with flutter that use classic bluetooth on iOS.*". That quote goes back to October 2018.

I found a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) that allows you to use classical bluetooth (weird as its based on a BLE package, flutter_blue), but only with android support and supports a max of 7 connections.

So:

1. Is there any package that allows for multiple devices to interact in
   classical bluetooth in both iOS and android? Or perhaps I'm wrong
   and BLE can be used for this project and I just don't see the way?
2. In the [package list](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=bluetooth) available for flutter, when selecting any
   package (for example the [first search result](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth)) where can I check if
   this package is for classical bluetooth or BLE? It's not specified.
   At the most, for this particular package, it states in the Reference
   section that the scan "Starts a scan for Bluetooth Low Energy
   devices." but other packages say nothing regarding the bluetooth
   type used.
3. And what is the point of people developing bluetooth apps in flutter
   if it can't support both iOS and android? Or in other words, why
   should I develop my app in flutter if it won't be usable by iOS and
   why not just change to android? What bennefits amb I not seeing
   here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Apps do not have access to legacy Bluetooth devices on iOS. The exceptions are audio devices, which are available via the AV framework and [Mfi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) devices which are accessible using the external connectivity framework.

Comment: does it mean we can not develop IOS apps that contains BL classic using flutter ?
@Paulw11

Comment: Not in Flutter, not in any language/tool (apart from some specific dual mode GATT use cases)