# Flutter_Blue can't scan my device. (My BT speaker) Android

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm new to Flutter and I'm working on a project that needs Bluetooth to connect to my hardware.
To my knowledge, Flutter_Blue works like this:

1. Get Flutter_Blue instance
2. Start scanning with `scan()`, also hook a listener to listen for new devices. (Which will return ScanedDevice, then add it to my list.)
3. From my list, pick a device I want to connect to, with `await device.connect()`
4. After a successful connection, discover its services with `device.discoverServices()`
5. `for characteristics in service.characteristics` to get characteristics from that device.
6. use `characteristic.read().listen((value){//do something with value});`

And I kept failing at stage 2, which is scanning for devices.
I somehow can't find my Bluetooth_Speaker with `scan()`, I tried using different scanning modes(Low latency, Low Energy, Balanced).

I can find other devices easily which is not mine(But they somehow don't have a name, all IDs are unique).
I have tried using my friend's phone as a device for my app to scan, but still no result.

With my android Bluetooth settings page, I can find the Bluetooth speaker (also my friend's phone) in the scanning new devices page.

Please tell me what went wrong I'll be very thankful. Thank you.

Environment:

- Sony XZ2 (Android version: 9)
- Flutter version: 2.0.5
- Dart version: 2.12.3
- sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
- flutter_blue: 0.6.3+1
- IDE: VSCode

Compile method: flutter run

Learned lesson(s) after viewing the replies:

1. Bluetooth_Low_Energy(BLE) cannot discover/connect to Classic Bluetooth. nor the other way(Classic -> BLE).

Comment: I suspect your Bluetooth speaker is Bluetooth Classic, while flutter_blue will only work with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices. Maybe use something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral to create a BLE device on a second phone

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't know that BLE cannot connect to Classic devices,  I search on the internet and I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480724/classic-bluetooth-package-for-ios-and-android-possible).

I'm currently searching for Classic Bluetooth packages/libraries. 
Let me try out the package which the thread mentioned.

Comment: I tried a different device, a wireless mouse, which uses LE service.
and Flutter_Blue can actually scan/discover the mouse.

Comment: What is the goal of your app? Can't you just connect to your speaker using the android settings and play some music in your app, which would be played on the remote speaker? Or did you just want to learn about BLE and use your speaker to test it?

Comment: I'm working on a project which involved both software applications and hardware sensors.
and my goal is to listen to my hardware sensor data and store it onto the server database. I used the BT speaker for testing because our hardware hasn't finished yet.

Comment: @Xia thanks for the info! I suggest you use a different smartphone and the app ukBaz suggested (or something similar) to test you app against a simulated BLE device (on the other phone). You can only find BLE devices that are advertising, an android smartphone without a special app does not normaly advertise.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, I couldn't find the app ukBaz on Google Play, But I'm thinking of making another app that uses Flutter_Blue to advertising services for my main app to test, Any suggestion? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Xia this is weird, I can find it in the store. Are you using a phone thats too old for BLE? Some apps restrict usage to specific features... But that would be weird, most current devices can use BLE... You can do this with many apps, 'nRF Connect' for example is a scanner and can also advertise a peripheral.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I installed the app 'nRF Connect' and start advertising, and it works! I can successfully found the advertisement using scan. Now I can proceed forward, using the write and read function to communicate, I have no experience in this section yet, I might run into another error or bug. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bluetooth has two types

- Classic
- Low Energy(LE)

Bluetooth_Low_Energy(BLE) is a technique that offers lower energy consumption, with a trade-off of slower transmission speed.
Classic devices can offer 24Mbps, where Low_Energy only offers 1Mbps.

**These two types of Bluetooth cannot be connected to each other.**

In this case, Flutter's Flutter_Blue library uses the Low_Energy service, and the Bluetooth speaker is used as a Classic device, That's why Flutter_Blue cannot scan/discover the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `flutterBlue.startScan();` instead of `scan()` ?

Comment: As I viewed the source code, `startScan()` seems to be a `Future` version of scan().
Both can be hooked by a `listener`.
I have hooked my listener to `FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults`, which can listen to both `scan()` and `starScan()`.